# How to mock the cls argument of a classmethod?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, class-method

I have a class that uses a *classmethod* as a custom constructor.

```py
# my_module.py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, my_arg):
        self.my_arg = my_arg

    @classmethod
    def my_constructor(cls):
        return cls("my val")
```

I would like to assert in a test that the constructor has been called with a proper value and the instance returned.

I tried several ways of patching, but I couldn’t get it working.

I tried patching the whole class, using the *wraps* argument to have the real method executed.

```py
# my_test.py
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch

from my_module import MyClass


class MyClassTestCase(TestCase):
    @patch("my_module.MyClass", wraps=MyClass)
    def test_my_constructor(self, my_class):
        result = my_class.my_constructor()
        my_class.assert_called_once_with("my val")
        self.assertEqual(result, my_class.return_value)
```

The problem here is that the *cls* argument that the _my_module.MyClass.my_class_ method gets is not my *Mock*, but the real *MyClass* class.

My other idea was to use *patch.object* to patch the real *__init__* constructor, but that doesn’t work either. This time because *__init__* should not return anything, but *MagicMock* has a return value.

```py
# my_test.py
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch

from my_module import MyClass


class MyClassTestCase(TestCase):
    @patch.object(MyClass, "__init__")
    def test_my_constructor(self, init):
        result = MyClass.my_constructor()
        init.assert_called_once_with("my val")
        self.assertEqual(result, init.return_value)
```

Is there an actual way to assert the *MyClass* class has been instantiated by the _my_constructor_ with the given arguments and returned?

Answer (score 0):

mock `__new__` instead `__init__`
and assert will be
`init.assert_called_once_with(MyClass, "my val")`